# How to update one table row with same keys by SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table T like this:

```
Name(Not unique)     Value   
A                      1
A                      3 
A                      5  
A                      8
```

And if I only want to update the 3rd row, how to write the SQL?

Below SQL does not work, it updates all the rows.

```
update T set Value='10' where Name='A'
```

Comment: is value is the key? if yes, then x2's answer is correct.

Comment: Tables have no inherent order. If you want to say anything about an ordering (such as "3rd row") you have to tell us (and SQL Server) what the rule is for determining the 3rd row. You need to define an order, based on the available column values.

Comment: Value is not the key, and it's not in any order.
What I want is just to update the row whose index I know in the table.

Comment: Then you cannot update the "3rd" row - there is no "3rd" row.

Comment: @SimonLiu: You could use *other* columns to define the order. Can you think of any existing column or columns that could be used in this way? If not, can you *add* one for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

```
update T set Value='10' where Name='A' and value=5
```

Comment: Is there some SQL that I can set the index?
Maybe my question is not so clear, I only know the index of the row but not its value.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE T SET Value='10' WHERE value=5
```